# How to solve this probability exercise?

Tags: probability

We have a box and we have on it 6 balls with numbers from 0 to 5. We push out 3 balls in the way that after pushing out a ball we turn it back again in the box. What is the probability that the sum of the numbers will be equal to 5. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  how many choices are there for the first ball?  Given what the first is, how many choices are there for the second ball? The third?  How many total choices does that make? That is your denominator. For he number of successes, you can do it as a [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)  problem, or (about as easily) just count by hand.